# PayPal JS SDK pass in custom trial days?

Tags: paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I'm trying to figure out how to pass in a "trial" period, or custom "start date" for a subscription. I have:

```
paypal.Buttons({

  createSubscription: function(data, actions) {

    return actions.subscription.create({
      'plan_id': window.my_config.paypal_sub_ids[window.my_config["period"]],
      'custom_id': $('#Email').val() + "----" + window.my_config["period"]
    });

  },

  onApprove: function(data, actions) {

        $('#AJAXloadingWrapper').show();

        console.log({ data: data, actions: actions });

        // all the rest is done on the server

  },
   onError: function (err) {
        // Show an error page here, when an error occurs
        console.log("ERROR")
        console.dir(err);
    }

}).render('#paypalWrapper');
```

This works fine. The problem I'm having, is that what I want to do is offer a unique number of free days to a user. A use case is that a user is already a paid member (one off payments), and they want to setup a subscription with us. So obviously you don't want the subscription to start until their current date has expired.

Is there a way to pass this in with the JS SDK? Or is it going to be a PITA where I have to create a custom price plan for that user, with the correct number of days set?

**UPDATE:** Alternatively, is there a way to "clone" an existing subscription plan, and then tweak the trial_days server side, ready to return to the front end for the JS side of things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a plan's details and create a new modified plan based on it.

The API call is https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#plans_get